# how to fetch all great grand children from a json object efficiently

Tags: java, json

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to fetch all great grant children from the root. I understand it is not the best way to store information but I have no control on why we have this structure. Here is my json

```
{
    "root": "some value",
    "other-attribute": "some value",
    "Level1": [
        {"attr": "value"},
        "attr" : "value",
        "Level2": [
            {"attr": "value"},
            "Level3" : [
                {"attr": "value"},
                "Level4" :[
                    {"attr": "value"},
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I fetch list of all "Level3" and "Level4" elements from the json. Do I have to traverse through each hierarchy then my program complexity would be O(n3) for 3 level and O(n4) for 4 level.

Comment: What is `n` in the complexity?

Comment: time complexity

Comment: No I mean, `n`, what does it mean? the number of nodes in the JSON objects?

Comment: In other words, why do you think the time complexity is `O(n^3)` ?

Comment: because i have to run a for loop for every child